# Powering On/Off Quectel BG95 LTE & GNSS module

Tags: transistors, pcb-design, lte

I have a Quectel module of the BG_95 series, for LTE and GNSS.  Haven't gotten to use it but am trying to integrate it with a PCB.  In the hardware design guide they list a circuit for powering off and on the module, [datasheet1.2](https://fccid.io/XMR202005BG95M5/User-Manual/Users-Manual-4826952.pdf) and V1.3[datasheet1.3](https://www.quectel.com/download/quectel_bg95_series_hardware_design_v1-3/) which is slightly updated but requires making an account to download.  I am confused by what some of the terms are like V_IL and V_nom?  Am I correct in saying that the pulse high has to be greater than 1.5V and pulse low has to be lower than 0.45V?

For the PSM wake-up (second circuit diagram) the description says it is rising edge triggered, pulled down by default, and 1.8V power domain.  What does this mean?

The description for powering off is as follows:
[image: circuit off]
[image: circuit off2]

The description for powering on is as follows:
[image: power on circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those voltages Vnom and VIL refer to the voltages the module outputs at PWRKEY. That's why they recommend using that simple circuit with a transistor, because you need to sink current to activate it.

You just need to connect a GPIO from your processor to the base (where that 4.7k resistor is) of the transistor. That GPIO should be pulled down by default (active high IO), and to turn ON the BG95 module, you pulse that GPIO (you put it high) during 500 to 1000 ms and then down again. You don't need to worry about the voltage output of your processor, the voltage at the transistor base can be 1.0, 1.5V, 1.8V, 3.3V or even 5V, most NPN transistors have a Vbe of around 0.7V, so any voltage higher than that will work.

As for the PSM question, 1V8 power domain, means that pin should see either GND or 1v8, so don't drive it with voltages higher then that. Therefore, don't try to drive it directly from a processor with 3.3V reference voltage at IOs. It's pulled low by default, means that the module most probably has a resistor tying this input to GND. This is saying that if you leave it open, it's ok. Rising edge triggered, it will be started by a transition from GND to a higher voltage.

Their proposed circuit is a simple way to wake up the module, based on a positive pulse at the PON_TRIG_EXT, while guaranteeing you're not putting more then 1.8V at that pin. When PON_TRIG_EXT is low, the DTC043ZEBL transistor is 'open', as well as the WM02P06L transistor, so the PON_TRIG will be 'open'. When you apply some voltage at the PON_TRIG_EXT, this will turn on the DTC043ZEBL, pulling the gate of the WM02P06L, therefore making 1.8V appear at PON_TRIG, this transition from low to high will trigger the module to wake. This means that at PON_TRIG_EXT you can use 1.8V but also 3.3V or even 5V, and nothing will burn.